# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have input json file @ [JSON](https://www.sendspace.com/file/6ik5ke) and when i try to parse it with below code:

```
<script>

    //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //after button is clicked we download the data
        $('.button').click(function(){

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "input_json.json",
                //force to handle it as text
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //let's display a few items
                    $('#results').html('Paper name: ' + json.Papername + '<br />Maximum Time: ' + json.MaxTime);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and HTML as:

```
 <input type="button" value="Get and parse JSON" class="button" />
```

When i click this button then i get error in Firefox console

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data`

Please help so resolve this out.

Comment: That link goes to a download service, it doesn't return the JSON directly.

Comment: @Barmar. i uploaded for reference.. ;)  ,, so that person can have a look #JSON

Comment: I tried downloading it, I got a `.exe` file, not JSON.

Comment: @Barmar.. i edited link. Please try now @ https://www.sendspace.com/file/6ik5ke

Comment: The whitespace indentation in the file contains strange Unicode characters. It should just be ASCII spaces and newlines.

Comment: How can i correct this JSOn file

Comment: No clue. Fix the program that created it.

Comment: Yes, indeed! It contains characters with UTF-8 code `C2A0` which stands for `A0`which is a "non-breaking space". It seems that these non-breaking spaces are not interpreted as whitespace by `parseJSON`

Comment: Thanks for the explnations.

I get JSON corrected @ `http://www.json-generator.com/`
and Now i am getting desired results :)